# Returning two cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath using segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control above two `UITableViews`, one of which is layered above the other. When `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1` one of those table views will hide. The problem, however, is that I can't configure the custom cells of the second table view in my one `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. I keep getting: `Variable 'cell' used before being initialized`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellOne

            return cell

        case 1:

            var cellTwo = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTwo

            return cellTwo

        default:
            var cell: UITableViewCell
            return cell
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have default branch with not initialized cell variable that you returns. I would recommend the change like following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let result: UITableViewCell

    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) { 
       var cellOne = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellOne
       //Configure here
       result = cellOne
    } else {
       var cellTwo = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellTwo
       //Configure here
       result = cellTwo
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: What's the solution then?

Comment: @dprek I updated my answer. I did an assumption in code that there is always some segment selected, so we always show either CellOne or CellTwo and there is no any other options.

Comment: And how would I configure, i.e., a label in CellOne vs. a UIImageView in CellTwo?

Comment: heh, it is another question, in your code sample there was zero references to a configuration. Give me a second to update the code for an updated requirement.

Comment: Nope, I'm getting `Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'`

Comment: @dperk You didn't copy return statement from my code sample. It is at very bottom of a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82022/discussion-between-dperk-and-nikita-leonov).